# Template parse error when doing prod build in jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-template, jhipster-gateway

When I do a prod build in jhipster, I get template parse errors of html elements.  The dev build works fine.

ERROR in Errors parsing template: Unexpected closing tag "button". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("class="btn btn-info" routerlink=../../ >  Back [ERROR ->]    ")

This is just the auto-generated user-management-detail-component.html file.

```
<button class="btn btn-info" routerLink="../../" >
     <fa-icon icon="arrow-left"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<span>Back</span>
</button>
```

If I remove the routerlink or change it to [routerLink]='["../../"]', it gets past this error.  Problem is that if it gets past this one, it catches on a div next and keeps getting template errors all throughout.

I have verified the html code and it is fine.  Ran it through a checker to be sure.  Like I said, it compiles fine under a dev build.  It only starts failing when I try to do a prod build.

Thanks

Comment: The prod build enables stricter template checking options, this is why it's important to start running prod builds from first generation of your project otherwise you may have introduced several breaking changes and it's harder to find which one. The problem is probably elsewhere in your code, so it's difficult for external people to help you.I suggest you rollback in time with git to run prod builds until you find which commit made it fail, `git bisect` could help. BTW, I removed your tag angular-ui-router because your question is about angular router.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information.  I looked through my git commits and started pushing back til I didn't have the issue anymore and worked forward from there.  I will keep an eye on th